# Delete Canvas Created Items? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

In tkinter, python, I'm currently trying to make a program so when a button is clicked a canvas created shape/line/text is hidden/removed. Here's what I've tried:

```
line = canvas.create_line(...)
line.configure(state=HIDDEN)
```

this just simply comes up with an error message, so I'd like some help with this. Thanks you for your time :)
- Jake

I apologise for my poor english skills

Comment: what error ? always put FULL error message in QUESTION. There is many usefull information.

Comment: Why would you try that? Are you reading some documentation that says that should work? It would help if you could tell us so that we can get the documentation corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas.delete(line)` is the function you're looking for. 
I advise you to consult online documentation on Tkinter before asking basic questions on SO. You can take a look at this [website](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) or [this one](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) for instance.